# react native maps UrlTile is not working with openstreetmap url on Android

Tags: react-native, openstreetmap, react-native-maps

this code works great with IOS, but not working with Android (emulator/real device)

```
<MapView region={this.state.region}>
  <UrlTile
    urlTemplate="http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    maximumZ={19}
    zIndex={99}
  />
</MapView>
```

can't understand where is problem

`UrlTile` works fine with this url `http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg` but not working with `osm` url `http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` although `osm` url works in browser

Android:
[image: Android]
IOS:
[image: IOS]

Comment: did your issue resolved ? I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a problem with OSM and not react native. I think you already got your answer (https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/3747), probably this helps others, solving the issue.